# Creating a hotkey so it copies our tooling from a defined map in to the map im currently in on windows 11

Tags: autohotkey, windows-11

I'm in the process of automating the majority of my tasks to minimize the margin of error. Currently, I'm exploring a method to, for instance, set up a hotkey (e.g., Alt + Ins) to copy tools from 'C:/Tooling/' to the folder I'm currently working in. From my research so far, it seems feasible to define an end folder, but not the folder that is currently open.

I have tried auto hotkey, but it seems that there must be something simpler than that.

```
^!c:: ; Ctrl+Alt+C hotkey to trigger the file copy
    ; Replace "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder" with the path of your source folder
    SourceFolder := "C:\test"

    ; Get the current location in Windows Explorer
    if WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; Check if Windows Explorer is active
    {
        ; Send Ctrl+L to focus on the address bar
        Send, ^l
        ; Wait for the address bar to be active
        WinWaitActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
        ; Send Ctrl+C to copy the path
        Send, ^c
        ; Wait for the clipboard to contain the path
        ClipWait

        ; Get the path from the clipboard
        CurrentPath := Clipboard

        ; Construct the destination path
        DestFolder := CurrentPath "\" (FileExist(SourceFolder) ? "" : "test")

        ; Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
        IfNotExist, %DestFolder%
            FileCreateDir, %DestFolder%

        ; Copy files using FileCopy command
        Loop, %SourceFolder%\*.* ; Loop through all files in the source folder
        {
            FileCopy, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, %DestFolder%
        }

        ; Copy specific folders recursively
        Folders := "Docs|Input|Tools"
        Loop, Parse, Folders, |
        {
            FolderName := A_LoopField
            SourceFolderPath := SourceFolder "\" FolderName
            DestFolderPath := DestFolder "\" FolderName

            ; Check if the source folder exists
            IfExist, %SourceFolderPath%
            {
                ; Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
                IfNotExist, %DestFolderPath%
                    FileCreateDir, %DestFolderPath%

                ; Copy files and subfolders from the specific folder
                CopyFolderRecursive(SourceFolderPath, DestFolderPath)
            }
        }

        MsgBox, Files and folders copied to %DestFolder%
    }
    else
    {
        MsgBox, Please activate Windows Explorer.
    }
return

CopyFolderRecursive(Source, Dest) {
    Loop, %Source%\*.* ; Loop through all files in the source folder
    {
        FileCopy, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, %Dest%
    }

    Loop, %Source%\*., 2 ; Loop through all subfolders in the source folder
    {
        SubfolderName := A_LoopFileName
        FullSourcePath := Source "\" SubfolderName
        FullDestPath := Dest "\" SubfolderName
        CopyFolderRecursive(FullSourcePath, FullDestPath)
    }
}
```